# Pictures not being filtered based on the logged in user

Tags: django

I am building a Photo Gallery as my last project. A Photographer can log in on the website and upload pictures in his portfolio. This part of the code works. However, the pictures are not being filtered based on the logged in user. Instead i get all the pictures from all the users like you would on a home page. I am new to Django and Web Dev in general and I've been stuck with this for three days now. I'll be grateful for any help and even more grateful for a decent explanation :). Thank you very much in advance.

I have tried to modify the query by using the get_queryset function but i probably lack the knowledge to do it properly. I have tried to match my user field with the user table, no results either. I am still learning half of how Django works. I came a long way just by going through some docs and tutorials but got stuck with this one pretty hard.

```
models.py:

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):

    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/img', blank=True, null=True)
    introduction = models.TextField(default='')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.email


class Pictures(models.Model):

    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='img', blank=True, null=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    CHOICES = (
        ("nature", "Nature"),
        ("animals", "Animals"),
        ("cars", "Cars"),
        ("cities", "Cities"),
        ("fitness", "Fitness"),
        ("motorcycles", "Motorcycles"),
        ("people", "People"),
        ("space", "Space"),
        ("technology", "Technology"),
        )
    category = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=CHOICES, default="nature")
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.picture


views.py:

class SignUp(generic.CreateView):
    form_class = CustomUserCreationForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
    template_name = 'signup.html'


class UploadImageView(generic.CreateView):
    form_class = UploadImageForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('profile')
    template_name = 'users/profile.html'


class ShowPortfolioImagesList(ListView):
    template_name = 'users/portfolio.html'
    queryset = Pictures.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    context_object_name = 'pictures_list'
    ordering = ['-date']


portfolio.html:

{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}Profile | {{ user.full_name }}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

{% if user.is_authenticated %}

<h2>Your Portfolio</h2>

{% for picture in pictures_list %}
<div>
  <img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}{{picture.picture}}"></img>
</div>
{% endfor %}

{% else %}

<p>You are not logged in</p>
<a href="{% url 'login' %}">login</a> |
<a href="{% url 'signup' %}">signup</a>

{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

I expect the Photographer to only see his pictures when he logs in, not the pictures of the entire website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class ShowPortfolioImagesList(ListView):
    template_name = 'users/portfolio.html'
    context_object_name = 'pictures_list'
    ordering = ['-date']

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Pictures.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

this should work. Probably you are missing `self` to access the request object